# Angular загрузка первой записи в ui-view при первой загрузке страницы

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, angular-ui-router, angularjs-controller, uiview

Здравствуйте, я не так давно начал изучать Angular.
Сейчас возникла проблема:
на странице есть блок

```
<div ui-view="probe_content" autoscroll="false"></div>
```

в который подгружаются данные из json по клику на ссылку

```
<a ui-sref="restricted.probes.details({ probeId:probes.id})">{{probes.name}}</a>
```

Ссылка находится в `ng-repeat`.

Все прекрасно работает, по клику на ссылку получаю id записи и через state url: "/details/{itemId:[0-9]{1,4}}" подгружаю темплейт с детальной информацией, но мне так-же необходимо загружать детальную информацию первого элемента при загрузке главной страницы.

Т.е. зашли на страницу видим не пустой темплейт со списком ссылок по которым необходимо кликнуть, а список ссылок и так-же детальную информацию первого элемента по умолчанию.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться сданной проблемой!

Ниже приведу код подключения.

*index.html*: (список ссылок)

```
<li ng-repeat="probes in menu.probe_list" ui-sref-active="md-list-item-active">
<a ui-sref="restricted.probes.details({ probeId:probes.id})">
    {{probes.name}}
</a>
</li>
```

*index.html*: (блок для подключение темплейта)

```
<div ui-view="probe_content" autoscroll="false"></div>
```

Файл states.js:

```
.state("restricted.probes", {
    url: "/probes",
    templateUrl: path_prefix +  'app/components/probes/probesView.html',
    controller: 'probesCtrl',
    resolve: {
        deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load( path_prefix + 'app/components/probes/probesController.js');
        }],
        probes: function($http){
            return $http({ method: 'POST', url: '/api/probe/submenu/' })
                .then(function (data) {
                    return data.data;
                });
        }
    },
    data: {
        pageTitle: 'Пробы'
    }
})
.state("restricted.probes.details", {
    url: "/details/{probeId:[0-9]{1,4}}",
    views: {
        'probe_content': {
            templateUrl: path_prefix + 'app/components/probes/probe_detailView.html',
            controller: 'probesCtrl'
        }
    },
    params: { hidePreloader: true }
})
```

Я думаю, нужно делать проверку, если параметра `probeId` нет, тогда делать редирект на страницу с детальном описанием первого элемента. Но как делать проверку и как делать редирект я не знаю.. Напишите, пожалуйста, пример.